# Working with partial tabview and soft keyboard in to edit text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a screen where the bottom half of the content is wrapped in a TabBarView while the top half remains constant. I want to be able to edit text in the bottom half, but the soft keyboard doesn't resize the entire page - it only attempts to eat into the TabBarView's space

[image: This Tab contains a scrollable ListView, so there is no overflow]
[image: Example 1][image]

My code looks like this:

```
return DefaultTabController(
  length: 3,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        'Edit Profile',
      ),
    ),
    //major column
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          UserInfo()
          TabBar(
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'INFO'),
              Tab(text: 'BIO'),
              Tab(text: 'ACCOUNT'),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            //All tab view content
            child: TabBarView(
              children: [
               Info(),
               Bio(), 
               Account(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hey @Yechi did you get your answer?

Comment: yeah, it works! Thanks! One last question, do you know how to force it to resize the top instead of the bottom?

Comment: I was able to get it working by wrapping the top half in Expanded and SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can wrap it inside a SingleChildScrollView:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
child: 
    body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              UserInfo()
              TabBar(
                labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                labelColor: Colors.black,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(text: 'INFO'),
                  Tab(text: 'BIO'),
                  Tab(text: 'ACCOUNT'),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                //All tab view content
                child: TabBarView(
                  children: [
                   Info(),
                   Bio(), 
                   Account(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
)
```

Or You can wrap the UserInfo() inside an Expanded:

```
Expanded(
              child: UserInfo()
            ),
```